# javascript is not working in rails4.2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

i am changing my rails application 2.3.2 to 4.2 but its not working in 4.2 please help me?  addwelllisteners in separate .js file function.and it is loaded when form will loded but in form it is not called?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
addWellListeners();
// Make sure we have no drag selection
$$(".plate").each(removeDragSelection);
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onComplete: function() {
$$(".plate").each(removeDragSelection);
  }
});

// Add right click context menu stuff
Event.observe(document, "contextmenu", function(event) {
// Only display context menu if inside the well area
if (Event.findElement(event, 'div').hasClassName('well')) {
 event.stop();
 showContextMenu(event.pointerX(), event.pointerY());
}
});
});
</script>
<% end %>





<% content_for :contextmenu do %>
<div id="context_menu" class="context_menu" style="display: none;">
<a href="#" onclick="addSelected(); return false;">Add</a><br />
<hr></hr>
<a href="#" onclick="editSelected(); return false;">Replace</a><br />
<hr></hr>
<a href="#" onclick="deleteSelected(); return false;">Delete</a><br />
</div>
<div id="context_menu_dis" class="context_menu" style="display: none;">
<span class="disabled">Add</span><br />
<hr></hr>
<span class="disabled">Replace</span><br />
<hr></hr>
<a href="#" onclick="deleteSelected(); return false;">Delete</a><br />
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.observe is not a function

Comment: and it is not displaying any error this function it self not calling

Comment: `document.observe` is prototype, rails switched from prototype in rails 2 to jquery in rails 3 I believe. So if you install prototype it'll probably fix it

Comment: i tried to add prototype.js file if i used it some of my ajax functions are not working

Comment: like page rendering and partial is not working